# creating an iostream object in c++

Tags: c++, stream, iostream

I'm going to try asking this again, but better than the last time.

I have a program that reads binary data in from various places, and then manipulates it in a class that I have written.  The data will be read originally from it's source (which may vary), then get written to a stream, and that stream will be passed into the class for the class to work on.

My struggles are with figuring out how to create an `iostream` and write to/read from it.  I have looked in various places and read the references at [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/iostream/), but I can't find a simple example of how to create an `iostream`.

based on what I've read, here is what I tried:

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main(){
    streambuf* sb;
    iostream s(sb);

    s.put('h'); //segfault
}
```

Frankly, I have no idea why its segfaulting, or how to fix it, so I am asking for someone to tell me how to properly create an `iostream` object that, ultimately, I will be able to execute something like the following on:

```
void printByN(iostream s, n){
    while (s.peek() != eof()){ // I'm not sure this is correct. need help with that too
        char buf [n];
        s.read(&buf, n);
        cout << buf << endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    //create iostream s;
    char* buf = "hello there my friend";
    s.write(buf, strlen(buf));
}
```

The point is I need the stream to know when it is empty, and return a special value at that point.  I cannot use a `stringstream`, because it is possible for the binary data to contain null characters that ARE NOT meant to terminate the data.

If `iostream` is the wrong way to do this, please let me know of a better option.

Comment: I would recommend getting a [decent introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), rather than trying to learn the language from scratch from random websites.  You should have much greater success!

Comment: You're right, that was an assumption, so apologies.  But your code above seems to have basic errors, like passing an uninitialised pointer as an argument to the constructor...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`stringstream` is exactly what you want. C++ strings *can* contain embedded null characters (`\0`).  If you don't believe me, [try it](http://ideone.com/z361sm).

`iostream` is really an abstract base class and has no real functionality on its own.  You should not be creating instances of `iostream` directly.

Comment: You're right.  The problem with the null character was not that the `stringstream` thought it was at its end, it was that the test of `while (s.peek())` was not working properly.  can you recommend the correct way to perform this test?

Comment: @ewok I would suggest `while (s.peek() != EOF)`. You can also test `s.eof()` or `s.bad()` etc. after the peek operation for more specific information.

Comment: it's telling me that `EOF` was not declared. and using `s.eof()` never reaches the end.

Comment: @ewok You would have to `#include <cstdio>` I think.

Comment: that works, except I was inputting `"hello the\0re my\0\0\0 friend"` and it terminates after `"hello the"`, on the NULL character, the same way it was before. I think the real question is probable, "Why is the eof flag not getting set?"

Comment: @ewok Yes, you need to explicitly specify the length of the input string if it contains embedded nulls. When given a `char const *` without a length, C++ string classes will find the length using the null-termination test. If you specify the length yourself, this test is skipped.